# Should I contact the editor-in-chief about a senior editor's lack of communication?

Tags: publications, journals, editors, journal-workflow

I submitted a paper to the top journal in my field. The journal's home page sets 120 days for a decision as a goal. Recent stats suggest 60 days to initial decision is more typical.

**It has now been seven months, with no word.** (The paper sat in the queue marked "Awaiting AE assignment" for two months, and has since been marked "Under review".)

Colleagues have varied in their recommendations about approaching the SE [Senior Editor] with a polite query as to when the review might be complete. Some advised strongly against it, due to some bad experiences with quick rejections following such a query. Others, typically more senior (and tenured) people, advocate a "wait and see" approach. Recently, I was able to speak with the former EIC [Editor-in-Chief] of a peer journal (a different journal, also at the top of my field), who very candidly advised me to contact the SE immediately about a decision. On his advice, I did so.

It has been two weeks without any sort of response with the SE.

I have chatted with other editors at this journal (AEs [Associate Editors] and SEs), and concluded this is likely a continuing issue with this particular SE. He is purportedly exceptional in his reviews, advice, and decisions, but not so much with timeliness.

As a very junior person, the status of this paper is very important for job prospects. My mentor (and co-author) takes something of a "throw me into the deep end" approach, and invites me to solve the issue without his intervention.

So, my questions are these: How long should I wait before contacting the SE again? Is there a point that I should contact the EIC or managing editor? (For context, as I understand it, the managing editor is a very junior person, effectively an administrative assistant to the EIC.)

---

May be similar to [Is it wise to contact the editor of a journals with my concerns regarding the length of the acceptance process?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/28305/is-it-wise-to-contact-the-editor-of-a-journals-with-my-concerns-regarding-the-le), and perhaps [How to let a journal know that its submission process is very painful?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/2677/how-to-let-a-journal-know-that-its-submission-process-is-very-painful), as well as some others, but different in seeking advice for escalation beyond SE.

---

*Edited to clarify EIC [Editor-in-Chief], SE [Senior Editor], AE [Associate Editor]. As I understand, SE is assigned by managing editor, based on content and submission letter. SE assigns a blind [?] AE. AE assigns/recruits blind reviewers.*

Answer (score 10):

The reviews are already 3 months overdue past the deadline. You have every right to ask for a progress update, if only to remind the editor in charge of your paper that you're still waiting.

I would write to that editor again, and if you don't get anything back write to him again with a CC: to the Editor-in-Chief.